# Cannot read property of undefined error although app behaves as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an app which is getting some data from an api and writing it to my template.  I can `console.log` the data and the data appears as expected in the template. However, there is still an error in the console

> cannot read property X of undefined.

I don't understand why this is happening, since the `console.log` of the data I need (which it says is undefined) appears BEFORE the error!

I've tried using `ngOnInit` instead of `ngAfterViewInit` and I've tried using an `async pipe`, but neither of these worked for me. I've also tried switching the `reloadanimals` Subject from a Subject to a BehaviourSubject. However, I might have been implementing them in the wrong way since I'm still relatively new to Angular.

A mockup of my template

```html
<div class="cards">
  <ng-container *ngIf="animaltypes$; else elser" class="mat-elevation-z4">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let animalname of ['frog', 'bear', 'cat']">
      <mat-card *ngIf="animaltypes$[animalname]; let animal" class="mat-elevation-z4">
        <mat-card-title class="animal-title">
          Animal: {{ animal.name }}
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content class="animal-status">
          Current Animal Info:
          <span *ngIf="animal.build_version; else elseBlock">
            Version {{ animal.facts }}({{ animal.foods }})
          </span>
          <ng-template #elseBlock><span>No Animal</span></ng-template>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-content class="animal-status">
          Pending Info:
          <span *ngIf="pendingData[animal.name].length > 0; else elseBlock">
            Version
            <span *ngFor="let pendingAnimal of pendingData[animal.name]">
              {{ pendingAnimal.facts }}({{ pendingAnimal.foods }})
            </span>
          </span>
          <ng-template #elseBlock><span>No Animal</span></ng-template>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elser><span>else</span></ng-template>
</div>
```

A mockup of my typescript

```
  constructor(
    private DataService: AnimalDataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  public type: string
  isLoadingResults: boolean = true
  public pendingData
  public animaltypes$ = {}

  getAnimals(type: string): Observable<AnimalResponse> {
    return this.DataService.getanimals() as Observable<AnimalResponse>
  }

  getPendingAnimals(type: string) {
    this.DataService.getpendinganimals().subscribe(res => {
      this.pendingData = res
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    merge(this.DataService.reloadAnimals, this.route.paramMap)
      .pipe(
        startWith({ stable: null, testing: null, edge: null }),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
            this.type = paramMap.get("name")
          })
          this.isLoadingResults = true
          this.pendingData = this.getPendingAnimals(this.type)
          return this.getPendingAnimals(this.type)
        }),
        map(data => {
          this.getPendingAnimals(this.type)
          let animals = new Observable<any>()
          for (let animal in data) {
            if (data[animal]) {
              data[animal].name = animal
            } else {
              data[animal] = { name: animal }
            }
            animals[animal] = data[animal]
          }
          return animals
        })
      )
      .subscribe(animals => {
        this.animaltypes$ = animals
        console.log(this.animaltypes$)
        return this.animaltypes$
      })
    return this.pendingData
  }
```

The `dataservice` just has some interfaces and basic get requests, I don't think it's the problem.

I tried to create a plunkr but I was spending so long getting it working I thought I would just post here and come back to it.
Here it is if it's any help. String interpolation doesn't seem to be happening at all in my plunkr for some reason, but this is my first time using plunker.

https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/IfgoJiXSaPzMIvgd

Everything is displaying in my actual app as it should, it's just the console error

> cannot read property "frog" of undefined"

that happens and only when I reload the results.  This makes me think maybe it's related to the reloadAnimals Subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the following:

- Your component gets created
- The component triggers the loading of the data
- While it is still loading, the component tries to render
  ==> But the data is not loaded now, so the try to access `animal`results in a "cannot read property "frog" of undefined".
- a few milliseconds later, the data is retrieved
  => The component is rendered again, this time with content

The console.log is irritating first. But I assume you are using chrome. And there you need to know one special behavior about the console.log. It evaluates its content not at the point in time when `console.log`is executed, but when you look at it (expand it).

That means when you took a look at the result, it showed you the updated content.

**How this problem could be solved**
One easy solution would be to use the "?" Operator in html.

```
{{ animal?.name }}
```

Another solution would be to not show the main content until the data is loaded completly.

The solution depends on what user experience you want to provide.

warm regards
Jan

Comment: I thought that if I used the safe navigation/ elvis operator then my template would keep inefficiently checking that the property exists again and again.  Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think @JanRecker is on the right track. I believe you need to combine the ? (check for existence) with async pipe, like this:  `{{ (animal | async)?.name }}`

Comment: Why doesn't wrapping everything in an ngif container do the job of the ? and async pipe though?  Surely if the object coming from the component is not defined, it should just show me my else block and not cause a console error?